Energy of a spherical shell
System: spherical shell with surface density.
Objective: calculate potential energy.

I found energy through potential.

Next, I found the formula for energy through the field, which gives two integrals, one in the volume and one in the field. The first when the surface goes to infinity, that is, for a very large $R$, the integral goes to zero. The second is the volumetric integral of the field squared.


My question is: why when the volume also increases, the integral in the volume is also not zero? Because if $E^2$ is proportional to $1/r^4$ and $V$ is proportional to $r^2$, which consequently the integral falls with $1/r$, and for very large $r$ it goes to zero.

If $r \to \infty$, all of the charges comprising the shell are "at infinity" and consequently have zero potential energy.  So the idea that the energy goes to zero as $r \to \infty$ makes physical sense to me.

You need to improve your question by specifying what energies and densities your are talking about. Gravitational fields and mass densities, electrostatic fields and charge densities? You have to edit your question to make  a clear statement of your problem. Otherwise the question will be closed.
